# Bazel test rule that only executes under certain configuration

Tags: bazel

I have a custom test rule that validates the size of a produced binary. I want this rule to only execute in a certain configuration (optimized, `--compilation_mode=opt`) and not run (or be a no-op PASS) otherwise.

Specifically,

- `bazel test //my:example_size_test` should not run the test (preferably, although running and always passing is acceptable)
- `bazel test -c opt //my:example_size_test` should run the test, passing based on the test outcome

Is there a way to achieve this?

I've tried using a macro to conditionally alias to the rule:

- `size_test` is a macro that instantiates

  - `$name_enabled_test`, the actual test target of type `_size_test`
  - `$name_disabled_test`, a `noop_test` rule (custom rule that does essentially `exit 0`)
  - `$name`, an `alias` that selects between `$name_enabled_test` and `$name_disabled_test` depending on the configuration via `select`

However, a hypothetical `bazel test //my:example_size_test` builds but doesn't run the test. This is [documented](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#alias):

> Tests are not run if their alias is mentioned on the command line. To define an alias that runs the referenced test, use a `test_suite` rule with a single target in its `tests` attribute.

I've tried using a `test_suite` instead of `alias`:

- `size_test` is a macro that instantiates

  - `$name_enabled_test`, the actual test target of type `_size_test`
  - `$name_disabled_test`, a `noop_test` rule (custom rule that does essentially `exit 0`)
  - `$name`, a `test_suite` that has a `tests` attribute that `select`s between `$name_enabled_test` and `$name_disabled_test` depending on the configuration

However, this doesn't work because the [`tests` attribute is non-configurable](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#test_suite).

Is there an idiomatic (or even roundabout) way to achieve a test that only applies to certain configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [select()](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#select).

Define a [config_setting](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#config_setting) for `-c opt`, and use `select` in the test's `data` attribute to depend on the binary. Also pass some flag to the test to indicate whether it should verify the binary's size or not.

I'll give you the example with `sh_test` because I don't want to assume anything about `size_test`:

```
some_test(
    name = "example_size_test",
    srcs = [...],  # you need to implement this
    deps = ["@bazel_tools//tools/bash/runfiles"],
    data = select({
        ":config_opt": ["//my:binary"],
        "//conditions:default": [],
    }),
    args = select({
        ":config_opt": [],
        "//conditions:default": ["do_not_run"],
    }),
)
```

If `$1 == "do_not_run"`, then the test should exit 0, otherwise it should use a runfiles-library (see for [Bash](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/d336dd85d7e53708311153cbf20270235633c406/tools/bash/runfiles/runfiles.bash#L15-L69), [C++](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/d336dd85d7e53708311153cbf20270235633c406/tools/cpp/runfiles/runfiles_src.h#L15-L76), [Java](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/d336dd85d7e53708311153cbf20270235633c406/tools/java/runfiles/Runfiles.java#L27-L67), [Python](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/d336dd85d7e53708311153cbf20270235633c406/tools/python/runfiles/runfiles.py#L14-L59)) to retrieve `//my:binary`'s location and test its size.